# How to merge two text (log) files, sorted according to timestamp using python only?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, mergesort

File1 is having timestamp in 1st entry, File2 is having timestamp in 3rd entry.Entries are separated by space.

Example: File1

```
01-01 **00:00:26.334** MODEM_CTRL: !!! Open /sys/devices/platform/
01-01 **00:00:26.335** MODEMD  : ro.modem.external.enable value is
01-01 **00:00:26.338** MODEMD  : TD modem is not enabled
01-01 **00:00:26.342** MODEMD  : W modem is enabled
01-01 **00:00:26.349** MODEMD  : It's w native version
01-01 **00:00:26.358** MODEMD  : enter start_service!
01-01 **00:00:26.360** MODEMD  : open stty dev: /dev/stty_w0
```

File2 :

```
<random_data> <random_data> 01-01 **00:00:26.333** c0 Booting Linux on physical
<random_data> <random_data> 01-01 **00:00:26.335** c0 Initializing cgroup subsy
<random_data> <random_data> 01-01 **00:00:26.336** c0 Initializing cgroup subsy
<random_data> <random_data> 01-01 **00:00:26.341** c0 Linux version 3.10.17-000
<random_data> <random_data> 01-01 **00:00:26.346** c0 CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410
<random_data> <random_data> 01-01 **00:00:26.349** c0 CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonalias
<random_data> <random_data> 01-01 **00:00:26.350** c0 Machine: sc8830, model: S
<random_data> <random_data> 01-01 **00:00:26.355** c0 mem_cs_get dram_cs_num=1
<random_data> <random_data> 01-01 **00:00:26.357** c0 mem_cs0_size_get dram_cs0
```

Expected output:

```
<random_data> <random_data> 01-01 **00:00:26.333** c0 Booting Linux on physical
01-01 **00:00:26.334** MODEM_CTRL: !!! Open /sys/devices/platform/
01-01 **00:00:26.335** MODEMD  : ro.modem.external.enable value is
<random_data> <random_data> 01-01 **00:00:26.335** c0 Initializing cgroup subsy
<random_data> <random_data> 01-01 **00:00:26.336** c0 Initializing cgroup subsy
01-01 **00:00:26.338** MODEMD  : TD modem is not enabled
<random_data> <random_data> 01-01 **00:00:26.341** c0 Linux version 3.10.17-000
01-01 **00:00:26.342** MODEMD  : W modem is enabled
<random_data> <random_data> 01-01 **00:00:26.346** c0 CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410
<random_data> <random_data> 01-01 **00:00:26.349** c0 CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonalias
01-01 **00:00:26.349** MODEMD  : It's w native version
<random_data> <random_data> 01-01 **00:00:26.350** c0 Machine: sc8830, model: S
<random_data> <random_data> 01-01 **00:00:26.355** c0 mem_cs_get dram_cs_num=1
<random_data> <random_data> 01-01 **00:00:26.357** c0 mem_cs0_size_get dram_cs0
01-01 **00:00:26.358** MODEMD  : enter start_service!
01-01 **00:00:26.360** MODEMD  : open stty dev: /dev/stty_w0
```

---

Question is different from the one, ift is marked duplicate of.
1> my files don't have any columns as entries are separated by spaces only.
2> Because that uses awk, And I need it in python only.
3> I don't want to merge only columns, I want to merge all full lines. the other one is just pasting column to first file.

Comment: this has been asked maaany times, did you do some research on the site before posting?

Comment: This might just be a thought: What about matching the timestamp using a regex and cast the the matchgroup as datetime or time object. Sort all timestamps chronogically and rearrange lines according to timestamps.

Comment: Yes I did research. and couldn't find similar one. However there are questions for "printing a column" but not for comparing different columns of different file and merging the whole file not only columns.